# Transaction updating database and crm

Tags: distributed-transactions

I have a scenario where I need to update both a SQL Server table and a Microsoft CRM record as one transaction, if one fails the other has to fail as well.  What is the best way to accomplish this and what technology should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with CRM 2011 or CRM 2013 then pre-event plugins are always executed within the database transaction and will be rolled back if there is a failure.  You can choose to execute post-event operations either within the database transaction or outside of it.

If the CRM table you mention is the one triggering the transaction then you should put the logic to update that table within a pre-update plugin and your SQL table update logic within a post-update plugin inside the transaction.

If the CRM table being updated is not the one that triggered the transaction then you should put both pieces of logic inside a post-update plugin inside the transaction.

In both cases everything will roll back if there is a failure.

Comment: Actually CRM is one system and the SQL Server is another database (this is not the CRM database).

Comment: I don't think that this changes the answer.  Assuming your post update plugin is running in a transaction and the CRM table update is executed first then a failure during the CRM table update means that your SQL update logic will never be executed.  If the CRM table update succeeds but the SQL update fails then the CRM update will be rolled back since it is executing within the transaction.